# How can I tell when an equivalence demonstration can be done bidirectionally?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, discrete-mathematics

I've been doing exercises that ask me to prove set equivalences like this:

> $(A \triangle B) \cup (A\triangle C) = [A - (B \cap C)] \cup [(B \cup C) - A]$

To prove them equivalent, there are two things I have to prove:

- The leftmost set $\subseteq$ the rightmost set
- The rightmost set $\subseteq$ the leftmost set

I have seen examples where proving the first one is enough. Basically, the example proves that the leftmost set is contained in the rightmost set using $\iff$ instead of just $\implies$.

Other examples don't use $\iff$, and instead prove both parts separately.

My problem is that those examples don't tell me **why** did they do that.

How can I know when proving a set equivalence will require proving both $\implies$ implications or just one $\iff$?

---

For the example above, I started proving the first $\implies$ like this:

Given an arbitrary element $x$:

$x \in (A \triangle B) \cup (A \triangle C)$

$x \in (A \triangle B) \lor x \in (A \triangle C)$

$x \in (A - B \cup B - A) \lor x \in (A - C \cup C-A)$

$(x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in B \land x \notin A) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin C) \lor (x \in C \land x \notin A)$

$[(x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin C)] \lor [(x \in B \land x \notin A) \lor (x \in C \land x \notin A)]$

$[x \in A \land (x\notin B \lor x \notin C)] \lor [x\notin A \land (x \in B \lor x \in C)]$

$(x \in A \land x \notin B \cap C) \lor (x \in B \cup C \land x \notin A)$

$x \in A - B \cap C \lor x \in B \cup C - A$

$x \in [A - (B \cap C)] \cup [(B \cup C) - A]$

After I did this, it became clear that proving the second implication would be pretty much the same thing, but in reverse order. So now I know that this demonstration could've been done with just the $\iff$. But I realized this **after** doing this proof. Is there a way to know beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $\iff$ if the operations you use to transform the set expression are reversible.

Sometimes when proving sets $A = B$, one of the inclusions is more obvious than the other one and sometimes they might assume that it's obvious to you and not state it.